# text extraction with R

Tags: r, text

I want to extract lines that starts with an "i" in a text file

I tried this

```
i <- grep("^i.", text,value = TRUE)
```

all the lines including iii and ii are extracted. How to solve this problem?

data

```
"i. provides substantial identification and comment upon significant    aspects of texts \\"                                                                                                                                                             
"ii. provides substantial identification and comment upon the creator\\'92s choices \\"                                                                                                                                                               
"iii. sufficiently justifies opinions and ideas with examples and explanations; uses accurate terminology
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to escape the `.` to read it as character `.`.  Otherwise, it means any character.

```
grep('^i\\.', text, value=TRUE)
#[1] "i. provides substantial identification and comment upon significant    aspects of texts \\"
```

#### data

```
text <- c("i. provides substantial identification and comment upon significant    aspects of texts \\", 
"ii. provides substantial identification and comment upon the creator\\'92s choices \\", 
"iii. sufficiently justifies opinions and ideas with examples and explanations; uses accurate terminology ")
```